# mysql connector/j not working with java jdk 1.7.x

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, java-7, mysql-connector, java-6

This subject was asked in a few places online, however did not find a solution and I have to say I find it strange.

I have a project that connects to MySQL using the following code:

```
    String params = "?verifyServerCertificate=false"
            + "&useSSL=true"
            + "&requireSSL=true"
            + "&authenticationPlugins=com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin"
            + "&defaultAuthenticationPlugin=com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.MysqlClearPasswordPlugin";

    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":"
            + port + "/dbname" + params;

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,
            uid, pwd);
```

The thing is it works using JDK 1.6 and mysql-connector-java 5.1.30.

But, I need to upgrade to JDK 1.7 and that's where I have issues.

> java.sql.SQLException: message
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:926)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1748)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2508)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2323)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>       at com.causata.automation.api.SampleApiTest.connectToDatabaseWithValidUser(SampleApiTest.java:357)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTestMethod(MethodRoadie.java:107)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:54)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:52)
>       at junit.framework.JSystemJUnit4ClassRunner.run(JSystemJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

I tried dubug the code with decompiler plugin for eclipse, but did not find much.
Looking for a solution in google I found some poeple saying I need to use a different connector version, I tried that too, different version starting 5.1.18-31

I think (not sure) that previous versions do not support the Authentication plugins being used.

Tried to use Spring and DataSource code, but under the hood it uses the same connector.
Tried searching for different connectors but again I am tied to the Authentication plugins, anyone knows for different driver that works with JDK 1.7 and support this kind of Authentication?

Tried also with JDK 1.8, got the same errors.

How can it be that I can't connect to MySQL using JDK 1.7 and above... it just does not make since.

I will appreciate any help given,

Thanks,
Eran